# bash who command does not give datetime correctly on testing

Tags: c, bash, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

Edit : We are still looking for differences that would explain why `who` does not work on testing for user lines (it works for boot lines for instance), this is differences on the code for following files :

```
--- ../lib/readutmp.c   2020-01-01 15:14:23.000000000 +0100
+++ ../../../testing/coreutils-9.1/lib/readutmp.c       2022-04-08 13:22:26.000000000 +0200
@@ -3 +3 @@
-   Copyright (C) 1992-2001, 2003-2006, 2009-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
+   Copyright (C) 1992-2001, 2003-2006, 2009-2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
@@ -7 +7 @@
-   the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
+   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
@@ -37,3 +37,2 @@
-#if USE_UNLOCKED_IO
-# include "unlocked-io.h"
-#endif
+/* Each of the FILE streams in this file is only used in a single thread.  */
+#include "unlocked-io.h"
@@ -95,2 +94,2 @@
-  size_t n_read = 0;
-  size_t n_alloc = 0;
+  idx_t n_read = 0;
+  idx_t n_alloc = 0;
@@ -112 +111 @@
-          utmp = x2nrealloc (utmp, &n_alloc, sizeof *utmp);
+          utmp = xpalloc (utmp, &n_alloc, 1, -1, sizeof *utmp);
@@ -131,2 +130,2 @@
-  size_t n_read = 0;
-  size_t n_alloc = 0;
+  idx_t n_read = 0;
+  idx_t n_alloc = 0;
@@ -135 +134 @@
-  FILE *f = fopen (file, "r");
+  FILE *f = fopen (file, "re");
@@ -143 +142 @@
-        utmp = x2nrealloc (utmp, &n_alloc, sizeof *utmp);
+        utmp = xpalloc (utmp, &n_alloc, 1, -1, sizeof *utmp);
```

and who.c :

```
--- ../src/who.c        2023-05-21 17:52:06.463931949 +0200
+++ ../../../testing/coreutils-9.1/src/who.c    2023-05-21 14:09:12.000000000 +0200
@@ -2 +2 @@
-   Copyright (C) 1992-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
+   Copyright (C) 1992-2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
@@ -94 +94 @@
-  const char *Var = ""
+  char const *Var = ""
@@ -194 +194 @@
-static const char *
+static char const *
@@ -224 +224 @@
-static const char *
+static char const *
@@ -252,4 +251,4 @@
-print_line (int userlen, const char *user, const char state,
-            int linelen, const char *line,
-            const char *time_str, const char *idle, const char *pid,
-            const char *comment, const char *exitstr)
+print_line (int userlen, char const *user, const char state,
+            int linelen, char const *line,
+            char const *time_str, char const *idle, char const *pid,
+            char const *comment, char const *exitstr)
@@ -518,2 +517,2 @@
-  strcpy (comment, _("id="));
-  strncat (comment, UT_ID (utmp_ent), utmpsize);
+  char *p = stpcpy (comment, _("id="));
+  stzncpy (p, UT_ID (utmp_ent), utmpsize);
@@ -686 +685 @@
-who (const char *filename, int options)
+who (char const *filename, int options)
```

I have a Raspbian OS with canonical sources (except I am on testing instead of stable).

When I do a `who` in bash, I get the following result:

```
frederic pts/3        3243058749271100071 (10.8.0.4)
```

I don't understand what is this number and why I don't have the datetime.
However if I do a `utmpdump /var/run/utmp` I get a corresponding entry with the datetime :

```
[7] [11526] [ts/3] [frederic] [pts/3       ] [10.8.0.4        ] [10.8.0.4   ] [2023-05-19T07:51:23,445095+00:00]
```

With some seconds (around 10) of interval between connections :

```
frederic pts/0        3243058749271099916 (10.8.10.4)
frederic pts/1        3243058749270864166 (10.8.10.4)

[7] [14197] [ts/0] [frederic] [pts/0       ] [10.8.10.4        ] [10.8.10.4   ] [2023-05-19T09:21:40,444940+00:00]
[7] [14244] [ts/1] [frederic] [pts/1       ] [10.8.10.4        ] [10.8.10.4   ] [2023-05-19T09:21:53,209190+00:00]
```

The version is : `who (GNU coreutils) 9.1`

Edit : I don't solve my issue but I therefore created another command that is working.

1. Create a file who.c

Type this code :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    struct utmp* data;
    char user[257];
    char ptyinf[65];
    char date[80];
    char ut_host[257];
    char ut_id[15];
    data = getutent();
    //getutent() populates the data structure with information
    while(data != NULL )
    {
        //Not a user
        if (data->ut_type!=7) {
                data = getutent();
                continue;
        }
        /*make sure to use strncpy
         *because most data fiels in the utmp struct
         *have ___nonstring___ atribute */
        strncpy(user, data->ut_user, sizeof(data->ut_user));
                user[sizeof(user)] = '\0';
        strncpy(ptyinf, data->ut_line, sizeof(data->ut_line));
                ptyinf[sizeof(ptyinf)] = '\0';
        strncpy(ut_host, data->ut_host, sizeof(data->ut_host));
                ut_host[sizeof(ut_host)]='\0';
        strncpy(ut_id, data->ut_id, sizeof(data->ut_id));
                ut_id[sizeof(ut_id)]='\0';
        time_t timestamp = data->ut_tv.tv_sec;
        struct tm *tm_info;
        //Set time according to locales
        tm_info = localtime(&timestamp);
        strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", tm_info);
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t(%s)\n", user, ptyinf, date, ut_host);
//      printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t(%s)\n", user, ptyinf, ut_id, date, ut_host);
        data = getutent();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please feel free to change the code if needed.

2. Compile the code `gcc -o who who.c`
3. Create a new binary in /bin/ (rename if you have already a binary with this name) :

Use sudo or root (to move the file and ensure it is owned by root, only writable by root and world-readable).

```
sudo mv -i who /bin/whoa && sudo chown root: /bin/whoa && sudo chmod 755 /bin/whoa
```

Then typing `whoa` in the command will display the correct who output.

```
$ time who && time whoa
frederic pts/0        3243058749270992894 (10.8.0.4)

real    0m0,011s
user    0m0,002s
sys     0m0,010s
frederic        pts/0   2023-05-19 18:57:06 CEST        (10.8.0.4)

real    0m0,010s
user    0m0,002s
sys     0m0,008s
```

Comment: odd, that big number should be a date

Comment: @JaromandaX Indeed but this is too big to be a UNIX timestamp...

Comment: can you log in about 10 seconds apart to see how the number changes - not sure that will help ... but ...

Comment: It is done... but it seems the number even goes down... Timesync is active and seems operational... The machine datetime seems very correct.

Comment: down by 235750 in 12.75 seconds ... nup, does not mean a thing!!

Comment: what model Pi and which OS? I've got many Pi's with various OS .... maybe I can reproduce :p

Comment: `Raspbian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid` on a `System: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1`

Comment: where do you get bookworm from for Raspi2? (you got me though, I don't have bookworm, but I do have a Pi 2 :p )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146124/discussion-between-joelcrypto-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: I have created a code to fullfill my needs but I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: Did you compile the OS yourself?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey not at all, it is a Raspbian OS from the imager with canonical sources. And coreutils comes from apt as well.

Comment: Have you tried asking on the official Raspberry Pi forums? As bookworm is still very much pre-release, I suspect bugs may still exist, maybe to do with Arm7 math?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I will try. Yes I seriously think it is a bug, I have sent it to Debian bugs but it might be needed to directly get in touch with Raspberry.

Comment: Interesting: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&keywords=bookworm

Comment: Could it be the host name of the machine?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don’t catch what is this about. And no the number is going up and down and even negative each time… I do some diffs on who.c and readutmp between stable and testing but nothing seems to be the cause.

Comment: If you want to use a pre release OS do your own testing but expect many things NOT to work.